'Strange' behaviour due to DC motor
TLD: How do I minimise noise / electrical disruptions created by a DC motor?
Situation
I would like to control a DC motor through DMX512. Therefore I connected a Max485 chip to an Arduino to receive DMX signals. The Arduino translates this to a PWM value so the motor driver, a BTS7960, can control the 24v geared motor. (see image below for the setup)
On the shaft of the motor is a disk with holes. Through an optical sensor, the Arduino counts the rotations and therefore knows the position of the motor.
The issue
Powering the motor gives electrical interference. This turns into 2 issues:

When the motor starts turning at full speed instantly (from zero to 255), the Arduino sometimes detects changes on the optical sensor pin (when it should not). The sensor pin is connected to an interrupt pin. (attachInterrupt(2, Count, RISING);

When the motor is spinning the DMX signal is disrupted sometimes.  The DMX interface (Enttec) continuously sends a value (eg 255) to the MAX485/Arduino.  When the motor is spinning the Arduino detects a 0 for a split second on all DMX channels (which makes the motor stop).


My guess
Something is happening on the ground / v5 lines to which the Max485, Arduino and motor driver are connected. Therefore I place all kinds of (big) capacitors. However, they don't seem to do anything. What do I do wrong here? 
For problem 1; could there travel an electrical signal backwards through the PMW wires into the Arduino that disrupts it?
Good to know

It only happens when the motor is spinning.
The disruptions happen regardless of the motor speed.
DMX wires are separate from motor wires.
I've tried these suggestions with no luck: https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J15/9#:~:text=Capacitors%20are%20usually%20the%20most,the%20motor%20casing%20as%20possible.
Sadly, I don't have access to an oscilloscope.


In addition, the setup has an optical sensor, buttons and I2C LCD screen; seemingly working correctly.
Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Using separate power supplies for the motor and the control electronics might help.

Get yourself an oscilloscope. Even the cheapest USB-ones without a screen would suffice to narrow down where and by how much your supply situation needs to improve or if the problem is elsewhere.

Hi @Hearth, After the 24v power supply, I could place a 5v step-down converter (mini560) splitting off in a power wire for the Arduino and a separate wire for the motor driver. Is this what you mean?

Hi @winny , Do you have any experience with / advice on usb-oscilloscopes?

@Qwertis Not really. My point is that you don't need a high resolution nor high speed scope to capture the problem in this case. Developing electronics pretty much requires a DSO.

The first thing to do is a reduction of EMI noise on the emitter side.
It can help to insert inductors in the range of 4.7-10 µH into the two motor wires. Connect the motor capacitor close to the motor, behind the inducors.
At the input side, RS485 signals and sensor input, it might help to add filter capacitors of 1 nF between the signals and GND, close to the arduino board.
Use thick, short GND wires between all modules. This avoids GND potential differences and inductance in the GND path.
Ensure, that your 24 V power supply can provide the motor startup current. You may need a capacitor on this supply as well. 1500 µF on the 5 V rail sounds a bit like an overkill to me.

Hi @Jens, Thanks for your answer!
About the inductors; would I place one in parallel to the vcc and gnd wires, or in series with each wire?

Insert them between the BTS7960 module and the motor, one in each wire. Use inductors, that can carry the motor current. So the noise generated by the motor brushes cannot reach the driver module and is not radiated so much by the motor wires. This has nothing to do with module VCC and GND.

Hi @Jens, I've got two lm2596 branching of the 24v power supply; one for the motor driver and one for the Arduino. Each has a dedicated 5v power supply. I've placed a 1 nF cap between de RO and GND of the Max485 board
I have added an extra 1000uF and 0.1uF cap on the 5v rail going to the Arduino etc.
Still, the DMX signal is interrupted and goes to 0 from time to time. Any other suggestions I could try? :) Tx!
The disruptions happen regardless of the motor speed.
